# angular universal connected postgresql issue

Tags: angular, postgresql, universal

I npm install pg on angular universal,  modify Server.ts import pg to connect postgresql, npm run dev:ssr ,show error like this .
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'pg-native' in 'D:\gitapp\ngex\node_modules\pg\lib\native'
resolve 'pg-native' in 'D:\gitapp\ngex\node_modules\pg\lib\native' ,
i try npm install pg-native ,but could not success.
but if on  a pure typescript express and connect pg ,there is no error.

```
 import * as pg from 'pg';
const config = { 
    host: '192.168.0.1', 
    user:"postgres",
    database:"pgdata",
    password:"pg123456",
    port:5432,
     max:20,
    idleTimeoutMillis:3000,
   };
   const pool = new pg.Pool(config);
```

Answer (score 3):

already solved ,i just check angular universal on github ,someone have this problem either,to solved this ,You can use the externalDependencies option. Which can be configured in angular.json.`"server": { "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:server", "options": { "outputPath": "dist/server", "main": "server.ts", "tsConfig": "tsconfig.server.json", "externalDependencies": [ "pg" ] }, ... }`